# can't map through array of elements inside of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I have an array object `productsByVendorPaginated` which contains nested array of data named `objects`. Here is the structure.

```
"productsByVendorPaginated": {
      "objects": [
        {
          "id": "d2e252ae-d0a9-4431-81ef-177c7fcacc16",
          "sellingPrice": 15000,
          "image": "http://ashewary.com/media/prod-image/1649447703.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is what I tried but I got nothing, just blank screen.

```
const DisplayData = datas?.productsByVendorPaginated?.objects
        ?.filter((vendors) => vendors?.id === id)
        ?.map((vendors) => {
            return (
                <div class="flex justify-evenly items-center mt-10">
                    <div
                        key={vendors.id}
                        class=" mt-10 grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5 "
                    >
                        <div>
                            <div>{vendors.sellingPrice}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
```

What's my mistake here?

**How can I map through `objects` array and display values in a `div`?**

Thanks

Comment: Hi Tesh. If you remove this part, is your app rendering correctly? Don’t you have any errors in your console? If you assign another value to DisplayData, like `const DisplayData = <span>Test</span>`, does that render?

Comment: Hi @Andy Yes It renders `Test` correctly.

Comment: can you attach initialization of `datas`?

Comment: why do you filtering array `objects`? probably each item is filtered out, try to remove filter